# Selectively apply \global to some tokens set via an \input file

Tags: expansion, input

This should be simple, but I can't quite guess the correct combination of `\expandafter` needed.  The value of `\MyTokenGlobal` should *not* be changed via the `\input`, but the value of `\MyTokenLocal` should change. The code below produces:

[image]

The desired output is:
[image]

### Notes:

- The `\begingroup`, `\endgroup` is necessary so that I can select which tokens get effected via the `\input`.
- Using an `xdef` where I have an `\edef` yields the correct result, but I think that might be problematic if the value of `\TempTokenLocal` were to change after `\MyInput` and before I used it. Hence, the request for a solution not using an `\xdef`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtoks{\MyTokenGlobal}
\newtoks{\MyTokenLocal}

%\usepackage{filecontents}% Commented to protect overwriting foo.tex
\begin{filecontents}{foo.tex}
    \MyTokenGlobal={Global XXX}
    \MyTokenLocal={Local}
\end{filecontents}

\MyTokenGlobal={Global}
\MyTokenLocal={Local XXX}

\newcommand*{\TempTokenLocal}{}% Temporary variable
\newcommand*{\MyInput}[1]{%
    \begingroup%
        \input{#1}%
        \edef\TempTokenLocal{\the\MyTokenLocal}% Don't want to use \xdef here.
        \global\MyTokenLocal={\TempTokenLocal}% <-- Need \expansion magic here I think.
    \endgroup%
}%
    
\begin{document}

BEFORE: 
MyTokens = ``\the\MyTokenGlobal/\the\MyTokenLocal"

\MyInput{foo}

AFTER: 
MyTokens = ``\the\MyTokenGlobal/\the\MyTokenLocal"

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtoks{\MyTokenGlobal}
\newtoks{\MyTokenLocal}

%\usepackage{filecontents}% Commented to protect overwriting foo.tex
\begin{filecontents}{foo.tex}
    \MyTokenGlobal={Global XXX}
    \MyTokenLocal={Local}
\end{filecontents}

\MyTokenGlobal={Global}
\MyTokenLocal={Local XXX}

\newcommand*{\MyInput}[1]{%
    \begingroup%
        \input{#1}%
        \global\MyTokenLocal=\expandafter{\the\MyTokenLocal}% <-- Need \expansion magic here I think.
    \endgroup%
}%

\begin{document}

BEFORE: 
MyTokens = ``\the\MyTokenGlobal/\the\MyTokenLocal"

\MyInput{foo}

AFTER: 
MyTokens = ``\the\MyTokenGlobal/\the\MyTokenLocal"

\end{document}
```